# How to submit a bug report to Apple's bug tracker?

Tags: xcode, bug

I managed to write a piece of code that made Xcode 5's LLVM compiler segfault. Xcode prints a message that asks me to submit a bug report at http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/. I try to do that, but all that site does is tell me what makes a good bug report, with no link or button where I can actually submit one. I have a developer account already.

So how do I submit a bug report to Apple's bug tracker?

Comment: I'm confused what your question is, is it how do I submit a bug or how do I submit a good quality bug?

Comment: @Steven How to submit a bug report.

Comment: @Steven I.e. where is the form where I can actually type something in and click "Submit".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that it's possible to log in without logging in.

Apple, if you send me to a page that makes me log in, LOG ME IN. Don't accept my login then send me right back to the landing page as if nothing happend.

Terrible UI design, Apple.